# Check if file exists on Android device with Kotlin

Tags: file, android-studio, kotlin

I'm newbie in Android development and doing on my first Android project and faced with .txt file handling.
I succesfully created a txt file on Android Emulator, which is stored in: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files/test.txt

My problem is, I don't know how to test with code if this file exists. I write next few lines, which I found on the Internet:

```
fun checkIfFileExists() {
    val fileName2 = "test.txt"
    var file = File(filesDir, fileName2)
    var fileExists = file.exists()


    if(fileExists) {
        println("File exists")
    }
    else {
        println("File doesn't exists")
    }

}
```

Function for file saving:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


        val file:String = fileName.text.toString()
        val data:String = fileData.text.toString()
        val fileOutputStream:FileOutputStream
        try {
            fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            fileOutputStream.write(data.toByteArray())
        }catch (e: FileNotFoundException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }catch (e: NumberFormatException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }catch (e: IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"data save",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        fileName.text.clear()
        fileData.text.clear()
    })
```

But it always prints "File doesn't exists", although I checked myself and file exists.

Hope someone knows what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiated the file with only the file name and no path, so how can it know where to look? On Android you don't want to be working with the absolute paths but with what the Context gives you.

Not sure how you created your original file, but assuming it was saved to internal storage, you would do this (`getFilesDir()` is a Context method, so will be available if calling from an Activity):

```
var file = File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), fileName2)
```

Comment: I changed my code as shown above, but it still tell me that file doesn't exists

Comment: How did your file originally get to be saved at `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.test/files/`?

Comment: I added code for file saving function to my original post

Comment: Try the updated line. Sorry I missed that `getFilesDir()` doesn't have the absolute path.